# Flex и margin-collapse (схлопывание)

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

В данном примере дочерние блоки `.row-green` не учитывают вертикальное схлопывание отступов, поскольку находятся в сетке flex. Возможно-ли заставить их учитывать схлопывание, не "ломая" при этом сетку `flex`?

```css
    
.row-green {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: green;
}

.row-red {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.row-blue{
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}

.col {
  margin: 15px 0; /* Вертикальный отступ в 15px */
}
```

```html
<div class="row-green">
  <div class="col">
    Отступы не схлопываются.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-blue">
  <div class="col">
    Отступы схлопываются.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-red">
  <div class="col">
    Отступы схлопываются.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У flex-ов нет свойства которое позволяет выходить внешним отcnупам дочернего элемента за flex-container.

Как вариант решение данной задачи

```
.row-green {
    margin: 15px 0;
}  

.row-green .col {
    margin:0;
}
```